# Is there a proper name for a program running on a microcontroller?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, terminology

I'm specifically referring to a C program that gets compiled into a binary and downloaded onto a microcontroller, which it then runs. Ex. When you upload an Arduino sketch.

I know it's not a user-space program considering we don't have an OS. I feel like just a "program" or "application" isn't enough.

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) that

> Microcontrollers are designed for embedded applications [...]

Which is the best name that I could come up with. I'm looking to put this on a resume, "Designed a(n) ______ for an ARM Cortex M4 Processor". *Embedded application*? *Standalone application*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: firmware is a word that is often used.  not hardware, but not completely soft either as in a product is is loaded once and ideally stays there most of its life.

Comment: Generally Embedded is the word used for microcontrollers. Firmware is also used. In your case, you can just put "Designed an application for an ARM...", as long as you have embedded and/or firmware elsewhere in the resume.

Comment: Also, resume related help is off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Firmware`**, as mentioned by [dwelch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16007/dwelch) and [Rishikesh Raje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555525/rishikesh-raje) in the comments,  would be the best match. Here is a part of the Wikipedia [Firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) article :

> In electronic systems and computing, firmware[a] is a type of software that provides control, monitoring and data manipulation of engineered products and systems. Typical examples of devices containing firmware are embedded systems

Embedded application is a good match but since it's a composed name it's not commonly used when embedded engineers talk about their software.

Comment: Microcode is something else entirely; that refers to the code that implements instructions on some CISC processors.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the information, I removed this term from my answer.